# Symfony and Socket.io

Tags: node.js, symfony, socket.io

I'm trying this bundle to make calls via node controller symfony
https://github.com/bazo/tembo

but I had to add exceptions for use as Would indeed

i want to call my function 'barno' in my node

Node.js

```
var app = require('express')()
    , server = require('http').createServer(app)
    , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(9001);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
    socket.emit('news2', { hello: 'world2' });


    socket.on('message', function(data){
        socket.broadcast.emit('broadcast-action', data);
    });

    socket.on('barno', function(data) {
        console.dir(data);
        socket.emit('barno', {profilo_da_seguire: '100'});

    });
});
```

my Controller

```
$client = new SocketIOClient('http://localhost:9001');

        $client->connect();

        //emit event
        $args = ['nome' => 'alessio'];
        $client->emit('barno', $args);

        $received = 'barno';
        $pippo = array();
        try {
            $client->listen(function($event, Message $message = null) use (&$received, &$pippo) {
                if($message !== null) {
                    if ($message->getName() == $received) {
                   $gino = $message->getArgs();
                        if (!is_object($gino[0])) {
                            $args = json_decode(current($message->getArgs()));
                        }else{
                         $args = $message->getArgs();
                            $pippo[] = $args[0];
                        }

                        throw new \Exception('Load');
                    }
                    /*$message = sprintf('packet: %d, time: %f, heartbeats: %d', $args->packet, $args->time, $args->heartbeats);
                    writeDebug($message);*/
                }
            });
        } catch (\RuntimeException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {

        }

        //var_dump($pippo);

        foreach ($pippo as $i => $pluto) {
            $pippo[$i]->nome= 'barno';
        }

        $client->disconnect(1);


        return array(
            'pippo' => $pippo
        );
    }
```

whit the Xdebug I see That
When the code arrive here

```
 if ($message->getName() == $received)
```

I have these calls

```
$message->getName() = "news"
$message->getName() = "news2"
$message->getName() = "barno"
```

i want only call the function Barno, how can i do this?

Than i add this

```
throw new \Exception('Load');
```

because the code entered in the loop

the result is

```
    array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[53]
      public 'profilo_da_seguire' => string '100' (length=3)
      public 'nome' => string 'barno' (length=5)
```

And this is correct but after unless calls

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

```
socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
socket.emit('news2', { hello: 'world2' });
```

lines from your node.js code.

Whenever the php client connects to node those lines are fired.

Comment: thanks for reply, use those functions for more events ... php capture all the functions that declare?

Comment: once connected captures all emits on his channel. use in to send on a different channel: socket.in('newsroom').emit('news', { hello: 'world' });

Comment: thanks again, i will try..but if i use an emit for all the page how can i do it ? for example profile page use emit for get some data

Answer (score 0):

These two emits:

```
socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
socket.emit('news2', { hello: 'world2' });
```

happen upon 'connect'. That means they will be emitted every time someone connects. And you DO connect. If you only want to use them for special purposes, create new listeners for them.